# Evaluate the limit of a complicated integral

Tags: real-analysis

I have a hard time working on the following problem. Please give me some hint.

Let $B_{r}$={$x=(x_{1},...,x_{n}){\in}R^{n}$ : $\left \|x\right \|{\leq}r$} ,where the norm is defined by usual Euclid norm. Let $u:R^{n}\rightarrow R$ be a smooth function and $u(0)>0$. Evaluate the follow limit

$lim_{r\rightarrow 0^{+}}$$\frac{\int_{B_{r}}(r^{2}-\left \| x \right \|^{2})\Delta (u^{2}(x))  dx}{\int_{\partial B_{r}}u^{2}  dS}$ ,where $\Delta$ stands for laplace operator.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I don't think there's much going on here: The numerator is $O(r^{n+2})$ while the denominator is asymptotic to a constant times $r^{n-1}.$